# Tkinter being extremely weird

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

So I'm making a programming language in Python.
This is the code I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as m
import sys

class IOscriptError(Exception):
    pass

class Std:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("STDOUT")
        self.stdouttext = [""]
        self.outstd = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.stdouttext)
        self.outstd.pack()
    def out(self, value):
        self.stdouttext.append(value + "\n")
        self.outstd.config(text=''.join(self.stdouttext))
    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

std = Std()

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def newButton(self, val, command="m.showinfo('title', 'message')"):
       self.b=tk.Button(std.root, text=val, command=command).pack()

gui = Gui()

std.out("Hello!")
std.out("How are you?")
gui.newButton("Hello!")
std.start()
```

The problem is that the button `gui.b`'s command is not running.
I've also tried with the use of [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda).
It just doesn't work!
Can you please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to pass a string as the command instead of a function. Instead of `command="m.showinfo('title', 'message')"`, try something like this:

```
def TestCommand():
    m.showinfo('title', 'message')
class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def newButton(self, val, command=TestCommand):
        self.b=tk.Button(std.root, text=val, command=command).pack()
```

Remember that the Button constructor takes a *function* as the command parameter and not a string.

Comment: Oh, ok... oh... IM DUMB! :P I used a string and not a lambda!